# Which DBMS versions Magento 2.1.18 supports?

Tags: magento-2.1, database

I am unable to find on Magento website or elsewhere, up to which versions of MariaDB and MySQL Magento 2.1.18 supports. I know it's old, but that's another topic.

I've found MySQL 5.6.x, I wonder if 5.7 is also fine?

https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.1.18

Comment: https://meetanshi.com/blog/magento-2-system-requirements/

Comment: thanks @Kushal so seems compatible with 5.7